# Could not read JSON

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have my controller like this following. `RelationType` is a field in `Table` class. I got the following exception. Any ideas?

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of com.mycompany.myapp.core.domain.RelationType from String value 'unionetomany': value not one of declared Enum instance names: [unionetoone, unionetomany]
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@7b3e44cb; line: 1, column: 435] (through reference chain: com.mycompany.myapp.core.domain.Table["relations"]->com.mycompany.myapp.core.domain.Relation["relationtype"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of com.mycompany.myapp.core.domain.RelationType from String value 'unionetomany': value not one of declared Enum instance names: [unionetoone, unionetomany, unimanytoone, unimanytomany, bionetoone, bionetomany, bimanytoone, bimanytomany]
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@7b3e44cb; line: 1, column: 435] (through reference chain: com.mycompany.myapp.core.domain.Table["relations"]->com.mycompany.myapp.core.domain.Relation["relationtype"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void validateSchema(@RequestBody Table[] tables, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ......
}

public enum RelationType {
  UNI_ONE_TO_ONE("unionetoone"),
  UNI_ONE_TO_MANY("unionetomany");

  private final String text;

  private RelationType(final String text) {
      this.text = text;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `Enum`s `name` is used for serialization, not whatever `toString()` returns. So while error message is confusing (it should list actual values expected), the problem is it expects `UNI_ONE_TO_MANY`.

If you want to use value returned by `toString()`, you should be able to add annotation `@JsonValue` to `toString()` method, and that should indicate that value should be used for serialization.

An alternative is to enable `DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING` which will change the behavior globally.